# LinearLayout issue Android wear

Tags: android, android-layout

I am designing a layout, which has header followed by wearable list view. I put in the below code, when I put the LinearLayout in activity to horizontal, I get my title and menu list printed neatly but I want one after the other. So I used vertical orientation in LinearLayout with which heading is printed correctly whereas the menu list is printed with just half of the first letter. How to fix this?

MenuLayout class is just linear layout. I am not doing any customization.

Activity layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_box="left|bottom|right">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:text="Menu"/>

        <android.support.wearable.view.WearableListView
            android:id="@+id/wearable_list"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">
        </android.support.wearable.view.WearableListView>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout>
```

Wearable List Item layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.example.menu.MenuLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>


</com.example.menu.MenuLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you're seeing?

Comment: I got it fixed by removing android:layout_margin="16dp" from TextView of MenuLayout xml